# django extensions hide pre and post imports

Tags: python, django, ipython, django-extensions

When I run python manage.py shell_plus there are many pre and post imports there. How can I hide them(I want to use it but not to see it). I use python 3.4.3 and ipython 6.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this task by myself.

```
django-admin shell_plus --quiet-load
```

Answer (score -1):

`shell_plus` imports all of the models from your `INSTALLED_APPS`, plus a few from Django itself. You can tell it not to load some of your apps and models with `SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD` but there is no way to hide the report of what's been imported.

Out of curiosity, why would you not want to? They scroll past in a flash and aren't in your way, and are sometimes important to telling you what's been imported from where.

You would have to contribute this feature to the project if you really need it, but I have to say it's hard to imagine a use case for it.

Comment: I have django app in the docker container and there is no history, when I  exit from and enter again, I should scroll up to the command(what I need), after that I copy and scroll down. It is not so convenient